# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded during date filtering

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to convert date input to '*yyyy-MM-dd*' format using angularjs custom filter i'm getting this error "**angular.js:11594 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**". Can anybody help me to fix this?

My filter is here

```
barnchManager.filter('myDate', function($filter) {

return function(input)
{
    if(input == null){ return ""; }

    var _date = $filter('myDate')(new Date(input), 'yyyy-MM-dd');

    return _date.toUpperCase();

};
```

});

And i have this statement in my controller

```
var filterDate = $filter('myDate')( add.date );
```

here is html form input

```
 <input type="date" ng-model="add.date" name="date" class="form-control" required  autofocus/>
```

[At this point i'm getting the above error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1SPt.png)

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: What exactly do you want this filter to do?

Comment: Sir i want it to convert my locale date input value to 'yyyy-MM-dd' format.

Answer (score 1):

var _date = $filter('myDate')(new Date(input), 'yyyy-MM-dd');

this line occur infinity loop

Comment: how can i avoid it or any alternative solution is there?

Comment: var _date = $filter('date')(input ,'yyyy-MM-dd')